# Remove /public from URL in Laravel when using dokku

Tags: laravel, nginx, dokku

I am deploying a laravel app with dokku and it deploys the app perfectly. The only issue is the famous `/public` problem. I need to change the nginx configuration inside the container somehow to make it point out to the correct directory. I found [this instruction about nginx configuration in dokku](https://github.com/dokku/dokku/blob/master/docs/nginx.md) but it doesn't give information about changing the root directory of an app.

Comment: Can you show the template you are using?

Comment: Given dokku uses the Heroku build packs, you should just be able to add the "extra" object to your composer.json. `"extra": {
  "heroku": {
      "document-root": "public",
      "index-document": "index.php",
      "compile": [
          "chmod -R 777 app/storage"
      ]
  }
}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to make a `Procfile` containing:

`web: vendor/bin/heroku-php-nginx public/`